# How to compare a forms particular field value with a string in lotus note replication formula?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

There is a form named Config and it has a field name as "Server" i need to compare this field with a string when replicating.

Comment: Do you want to replicate the config document (depending on field Server) only or all documents when config document contains in field Server a certain server name?

Comment: @KnutHerrmann Yes, i want replicate the config document (depending on field server) only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula

```
SELECT Form = "Config" & Server = "YourServer"
```

would replicate only Config documents (when field Server is "YourServer"), no other documents.

[image]